# What's the reason behind using UL Li lists to draw navigation bars?

Tags: html, css

I have seen css navigation designs done mostly through `ul` and `li` lists for the tab structure. What is the reason behind this?. What is the fall-back for such sites if css is somehow disabled?

Comment: You'll get a "list" of links which is what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Accessibility for i.e. screen readers and even fallback for non css browsers. Maintain semantics in HTML < 5.

Comment: @DanielB i didnt got your comment.How is fallback for non css browsers done. When doing navigation through ul li's

Comment: @sushil it will be displayed as a unordered list where the list items are navigation links. This much better than lest say divs, which will be displayed one after another with no visible connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semantic markup has various reasons, for example:

- screen readers can access the site more easily
- google bot can crawl the site more easily

This link gives more detail on the topic: [Semantic HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML).
Besides, it is HIGHLY unlikely someone will have CSS disabled. In my opinion there is absolutely no need to provide fallback for that case, the navigation would still be accessible anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is no concrete reason, that is there is no rule book that states you **MUST** do navigation links using a UL LI list.

However, for the 2 reasons all ready given in the comments, and W3C recommendations about document structure , layout and html semantics, then it is ** RECOMMENDED** that navigation links be performed in that manner.

It's much like conforming to patterns in code, by using standards compliant structures and methods, the next person that has to maintain that site after you can look at it and say, *ahh ... I see whats going on here*.

As for screen readers, they (as has been mentioned) can also do a similar analysis on the document layout, and thus decide which elements are important to a visually impaired user.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation is a menu, in older html there was a  tag, deprecated in html4 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.4) because menu and ul renders the same.

Now navigation menu  in html5 must be contanined in the semantic  tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a pattern that worked well when it was developed (in all browsers), so it was documented in CSS books and used by a lot of people. You don't have to change too much (`ul { list-style: none;}` and `li { display: inline; }`), so it is easy to add. And if you disable CSS in your browser, you just get a more ugly version which is working as well.